# Just starting to learn CSS and struggling with display

Tags: html, css, display

I have this

```css
.name-bar,
.email-bar {
  border-color: gray;
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

.email-bar {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.div-one,
.div-two {
  border-color: gray;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input class="name-bar" type="text" placeholder="Name">
<input class="email-bar" type="text" placeholder="Email">

<div class="div-one"></div>
<div class="div-two"></div>
```

This produces 2 input fields next to each other on the same line followed by 2 DIVs on that same line.  What I want to do is have the 2 input fields stacked vertically on each other instead of horizontally followed by the 2 divs as they are.

I have played around with the CSS display in a variety of ways but I just do not understand what I need to do to achieve that desired alignment.

Comment: Not sure how to embed the HTML - it lets me add the style info with grave accent character but not sure how to have HTML come through - I am new here :)

Comment: Ah alright :) you can create a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) when editing the question. Look for the `<>` icon. That allows you to create a runnable snippet and add it to the question.

Comment: Fixed the before and after posts.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it to work.  I set a div around the 2 input boxes and set the div to inline-block. Then I set the second input inside a paragraph tag.  The 2 divs and the 2 inputs are still styled as display: inline-block.  But that did the trick.

Thanks!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
  <head>

    <title>CSS display</title>

    <style>
      p{
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
      }

      .container{
        display:inline-block;
      }

      .name-bar,
      .email-bar{
        border-color: gray;
        border-style: solid;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .div-one, .div-two{
        border-color: gray;
        border-style: solid;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        vertical-align: top;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    </style>
  
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <div class="container">
      <input class="name-bar" type="text" placeholder="Name">
      <p><input class="email-bar" type="text" placeholder="Email"></p>
    </div>  
    <div class="div-one"></div>
    <div class="div-two"></div>

   </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: That was a typo in my comment here but thanks :)

Comment: Alright, got it. Just another note: explaining your solution is alright, but *showing* your solution is better. Consider adding your code so others might benefit from your findings.

Comment: it is "technically" possible to place an <input> element inside a <p> But I won't do that.

Comment: HM23 - Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `display: block;` OR use Flexbox!

something like this:

```
<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .name-bar,
  .email-bar{
    border-color: gray;
    border-style: solid;
  }

  .div-one, .div-two{
    border-color: gray;
    border-style: solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="name-bar">
  <input type="email" class="email-bar">
</div>
<div class="div-one"></div>
<div class="div-two"></div>
```

Comment: display:block on which HTML control?

Comment: Now the input fields are correctly aligned vertically but they now occupy the entire width of the page and the 2 DIV boxes are moved below the 2 input boxes

Comment: I mean change the (.name-bar,  .email-bar) display: inline-block; to : display: block;!

If they are occupying the whole width you can set the (.name-bar,  .email-bar) width: 200px; for example and add some margins

Answer (score 0):

Although there are multiple ways to approach this, I would suggest that you familiarize yourself with [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

The main difference between these tools and legacy `inline-block` / `block` is that you get more control over the way elements are placed inside of a container. It allows you to *tell* the browser how every thing should be placed, spaced and aligned with ease.

In the example below I've used both tools. Grid to create the layout of the container and the two divs, and Flexbox to stack the inputs. Now the inputs would be stacked anyway, but using Flexbox forces the layout to always stay stacked and gives you additional controls on how the inputs should be aligned on the X and Y axes.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);
  grid-template-rows: 200px;
  gap: 15px;
}

.inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 5px;
}

.name-bar,
.email-bar,
.div-one,
.div-two {
  border: gray solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="inputs">
    <input class="name-bar" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    <input class="email-bar" type="text" placeholder="Email">
  </div>

  <div class="div-one"></div>
  <div class="div-two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Emiel!  I am currently using a curriculum to learn CSS and display was something just covered in the course and I was struggling with it a bit.  I suspect they will cover Grid and Flexbox soon.  Right now they are covering nested design.  I must say I really like the cleaner approach of grid and flex that you show here though.

Comment: You're welcome. Cool that you're learning CSS, especially in this day and age. That almost makes me sound old, but CSS has rapidly progressed in the last years and a lot of *very useful* features have been introduced since then. Have fun learning and don't forget to mark an answer as accepted which you feel answers the question best.